# python __str__ for an object

Tags: python

While trying to figure out how BeautifulSoup works, I incidentally learnt the `__str__` method (I'm new to python). So if I did not misperceived then the `__str__` method helps to shape how the class will be represented if printed out. For instance:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return "bar"

>>> x = Foo()
>>> print x
bar
```

Right? So asserting that I'm right, is it possible to override the `__str__` method of a list of dictionaries? I mean say that in class Foo you have:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.l = [{"Susan": ("Boyle", 50, "alive")}, {"Albert": ("Speer", 106, "dead")}]
```

Now is it possible to have the following outcome?

```
>>> x = Foo()
>>> print x.l
"Susan Boyle is 50 and alive. Albert Speer is 106 and dead."
```

**EDIT**

Considering agf's solution, how can I access the dictionary once again? I mean if I define `__str__` method then apparently I should define something else to retrieve the dictionary as it is. Please consider the following example:

```
class PClass(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        # code to return the result that I want 

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = PClass({"Susan": ["Boyle", ........ })

>>> x = Foo()
>>> print x.l 
# result that works great
>>> y = x.l["Susan"] # this would not work. How can I achieve it?
```

Comment: Not without subclassing dict, no.

Comment: No, although you can certainly design your `Foo` class to store the same information in a way that would allow pretty-printing. You can't change a list's `__str__` method; it's built-in.

Comment: By the way, if you want to know more about `__str__` and similar methods, I suggest reading e.g. [this article](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html). These methods are called "magic" members or methods.

Comment: @Martin thanks a lot I'll read it right away

Comment: Is this a use case for descriptors?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to subclass the item you're pretty-printing.

```
from itertools import chain

class PrintableList(list): # for a list of dicts
    def __str__(self):
        return '. '.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in
            chain.from_iterable(zip((item[0], 'is', 'and'), item[1])))
                for item in (item.items()[0] for item in self)) + '.'

class PrintableDict(dict): # for a dict
    def __str__(self):
        return '. '.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in
            chain.from_iterable(zip((item[0], 'is', 'and'), item[1])))
                for item in self.iteritems()) + '.'

class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.d = PrintableDict({"Susan": ("Boyle", 50, "alive"), 
                              "Albert": ("Speer", 106, "dead")})

class Bar:
   def __init__(self):
      self.l = PrintableList([{"Susan": ("Boyle", 50, "alive")}, 
                              {"Albert": ("Speer", 106, "dead")}])

foo = Foo()
print self.d
bar = Bar()
print self.l
```

Comment: congrats on 10k by the way :)

Comment: Thanks. I lost my internet connection for a few minutes but now I fixed it so the `__str__` actually works for the example (not that that matters)

Comment: You need to look back at your question again :). You had a _list of dictionaries_, so you can't access them by name. If you want to access them by name, you need to make the whole thing a dictionary. It has nothing to do with the string method.

Comment: I updated my answer with a version for a dict. It's almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to override `__getattribute__`, which lets you customize how attributes are returned:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [{"Susan": ("Boyle", 50, "alive")}, {"Albert": ("Speer", 106, "dead")}]

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return PrintableList(l)
        attr = super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)
        items = sum([x.items() for x in attr], [])
        return ' '.join([' '.join([k, v[0], 'is', str(v[1]), 'and', v[2] + '.']) for k,v in items])

>>> f = Foo()
>>> print f.l
<<< Susan Boyle is 50 and alive. Albert Speer is 106 and dead.
```

Comment: This is also an interesting approach. Thanks!

Comment: **+1** as you don't have to define a new class and worry about sub-classing and stuff. You also get to use a default -- always a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You could define `__str__` for your Foo class to return what you want:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [{"Susan": ("Boyle", 50, "alive")}, {"Albert": ("Speer", 106, "
dead")}]
    def __str__(self):
        ret_str = ""
        for d in self.l:
            for k in d:
                ret_str += "".join([k, " ", d[k][0], " is ", str(d[k][1]), " and
 ", d[k][2], ". "])
        return ret_str

foo = Foo()
print foo
```

results in:

> Susan Boyle is 50 and alive. Albert Speer is 106 and dead.