# Return key and value dict from list with dicts using __str__

Tags: python, dictionary

I try create class, which will return values to pretty print.
I found this post [python __str__ for an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152312/python-str-for-an-object)
 but I still can't understand how I can improve my class.

Here is my class:

```
class PrintList(): 
    def __init__(self,lista):
        self.lista=lista
    def __str__(self):
        if isinstance(x[0] in self.lista, dict):           #for dicts in list
            return ','.join(str(item),'->',str(item[x]) for x in item) for item in self.lista
        else:         # for variables in list
            return ','.join(str(x) for x in self.lista)
```

and bug in first return:

```
return ','.join(str(item),'->',str(item[x]) for x in item) for item in self.lista
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I try get the following result:
key_dict->value_dict, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have an invalid syntax in your comprehension/generator expression.

You should have written the expression as follows

```
return ','.join("{}->{}".format(item, item[x]) for x in item for item in self.lista)
```

**Offtopic**

As @MartijnPieter, for `str.join`, its faster to use a list comprehension rather than a generator expression notably because it needs to generate the data before stitching them togeter (a two pass algorithm). Please refer [list comprehension without [ ], Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024)

Comment: I'd use a list comprehension and not a generator expression; it is faster *for `str.join()`*. See [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know. I am just using the same format as OPs without introducing new concepts or digressing from the topic. If you see, OP is already using a generator expression, and I did not think would make sense to convert it to a list.

Comment: *shrug*. I'd add an extra paragraph explaining that a list comp would be the better option here and link to Raymond's answer, that's all. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok, I have added a paragraph in the answer.