# Python AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'print'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in this website so sorry if I am doing something absurd or against rules but I have a question.

I am new to Python and programming. I am learning Python and when I am exercising I encountered and Error. I searched for solutions here but most of them was above my level that I couldn't understand.

Please try to answer in a way a beginner can understand, thank you.

Here is the code and the Error I get is; 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'print''

Thanks for any help.

```
import random


class Enemy:
    name = "Enemy"
    health = 100
    damage = 5
    ammo = 20

    def __init__(self,name,health,damage,ammo):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.ammo = ammo

    def properties(self):
        print("Properties: ")
        print("Name: ",self.name)
        print("Health: ",self.health)
        print("Damage: ",self.damage)
        print("Ammo: ",self.ammo)

    def attack(self):
        print(self.name + " is attacking!")
        ammo_spent = random.randrange(1,10)
        print(str(ammo_spent) + " ammo spent.")
        self.ammo -= ammo_spent
        return (ammo_spent,self.damage)

    def getattacked(self,ammo_spent,damage):
        print ("I've been shot!")
        self.health -= (ammo_spent * damage)

    def is_ammo_depleted(self):
        if (self.ammo <= 0):
            print (self.name + "'s ammo depleted.")
            return True
        return False
    def check(self):
        if (self.health <= 0):
            print("YOU DIED.")




Enemies = []

i = 0
while (i < 9):
    randomhealth = random.randrange(125,300,25)
    randomdamage = random.randrange(25,100,25)
    randomammo = random.randrange(20,200,20)
    new_enemy = ("Enemy" + str(i+1),randomhealth,randomdamage,randomammo)
    Enemies.append(new_enemy)

    i += 1

for Enemy in Enemies:
    Enemy.properties()
```

Comment: As the error message says, the `Enemy` class has no method `print`. If you want to be able to call `.print()` on an `Enemy` instance, you have to define a `print()` method.

Comment: replace `Enemy.print()` by `Enemy.properties()`  ... or do a `__str__(self):` method and do `print(Enemy)`

Comment: I tried     Enemy.properties()    before but I got the same error just properties instead of print. Where should I insert the __str__(self)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152312/python-str-for-an-object - you return a string from it

Comment: You are not creating enmies _ you are creating tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create instances of your class:

```
Enemies = []

i = 0
while (i < 9):
    randomhealth = random.randrange(125,300,25)
    randomdamage = random.randrange(25,100,25)
    randomammo = random.randrange(20,200,20)

    # create an Enemy - not a tuple of values
    new_enemy = Enemy( "Enemy {}".format(i), randomhealth, randomdamage, randomammo)
    Enemies.append(new_enemy)

    i += 1

for Enemy in Enemies:
    Enemy.properties()
```

If you create a `__str__(self)` method in your class you can "tell" python how to print an instance of your class:

```
class Enemy:
    # snipped what you already had

    # is used if you print(instance)
    def __str__(self):
        return  """Properties:
Name: {}
Health: {}
Damage: {}
Ammo:   {}""".format(self.name, self.health, self.damage, self.ammo)

    # is used by lists if you print a whole list
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Read about `__str__` here: [python __str__ for an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152312/python-str-for-an-object)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I forgot to type Enemy before () and after new_enemy. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off, don't do shenanigans like

```
i = 0
while (i < 9):
    i++
    // bad
```

use

```
for i in range(9):
   // good
```

instead.

Second off, with

```
new_enemy = ("Enemy" + str(i+1),randomhealth,randomdamage,randomammo)
Enemies.append(new_enemy)
```

you're appending a Tuple to your Entities list. How could you possibly expect that Tuple to have the properties of your Entity class?

So what you want to use instead is

```
Enemies = []

for i in range(9):
    randomhealth = random.randrange(125,300,25)
    randomdamage = random.randrange(25,100,25)
    randomammo = random.randrange(20,200,20)
    new_enemy = Enemy("Enemy" + str(i+1), randomhealth, randomdamage, randomammo)
    Enemies.append(new_enemy)

for Enemy in Enemies:
    Enemy.print()
```

Next, in your last for loop, you're using the class name Enemy as a variable in the loop. Terrible idea, but luckily you can just make that lowercase.
So, why does it STILL say that your Enemy class has no print member? Because you haven't defined one, you called the method "properties" instead.

```
for enemy in Enemies:
    enemy.properties()
```

And it works.
However, since we're in python, we can simplify this code quite a lot.

Endresult:

```
import random


class Enemy:

    def __init__(self,name,health,damage,ammo):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.ammo = ammo

    def __str__(self):
        return "Properties:\nName: {}\nHealth: {}\nDamage: {}\nAmmo: {}".format(
            self.name, self.health, self.damage, self.ammo)

    #your other methods

Enemies = [Enemy(name="Enemy" + str(i),
                 health=random.randrange(125, 300, 25),
                 damage=random.randrange(25, 100, 25),
                 ammo=random.randrange(20, 200, 20))
           for i in range(1, 10)]

for enemy in Enemies:
    print(enemy)
```