# Get permID within an list in Interactive Brokers using Python

Tags: python

This code:

```
open_trades = ib.trades() #Interactive Brokers function
for i in range(0,len(open_trades)):
     print(open_trades[i].orderStatus
```

prints OrderStatus(status='Submitted', remaining=1000.0, **permId**=1036207528, clientId=1)

Now how do I get the **permID**?

The answer should look something like this (I tried many other things too):

```
open_trades[i].orderStatus.permID #no attribute error
open_trades[i].orderStatus.OrderStatus.permID #no attribute error
open_trades[i].orderStatus[0].permID #gets error 'OrderStatus' object does not support indexing
```

The last attempt is most likely the closest answer which gets the error:

> 'OrderStatus' object does not support indexing

Comment: Ok. I will try to simplify it without the loop and ask again. I thought this was going to be an easy solutiion, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are struggling with is related to `__str__` implementation for objects in Python (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152312/python-str-for-an-object)).

Object can implement a custom `__str__` method therefore printing a **string representation** of the object. However, it can be confusing, as it does not necessarily corresponds to the structure of the object (and its properties).

Not knowing what libraries you use ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be handy here) I suggest checking the available methods and object variables under debugger and then using them to access the properties you want.

Comment: I just realized I had a small typo. permID should have been permId. Therefore, this topic can be deleted if a mod requests.

Comment: You have permissions to delete your own posts. You are welcome to do it!